# Route Traffic by Sub-domain Through an Internet Gateway?

Tags: domain-name-system, routing

I'm attempting to set up two web servers behind one internet gateway/router (we can call them dev and production for example). I would like to be able to access them by URL as dev.mydomain.com and prod.mydomain.com.

I have a static IP and can create the appropriate DNS A-record(s). But all such A-records will have to point to my single external IP address. Is there a way to route traffic to a specific server based on sub-domain?

Comment: Routers route packets by the destination address in the packet headers, and the packets only have the source and destination IP addresses in the packet headers. IP knows nothing about DNS names.

Comment: Right... So with the parameters I put in my question, it can't be done. What I would have to do is get two external addresses assigned to my router, and have my router send port 80+443 incoming from different external IPs to different internal IPs... Probably not cost effective for my limited uses (Since I would need a different router and modified internet contract).